# Exclude specific Google Drive folders from Google Photos

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Is it possible to have Google only include specific directories from my Drive within Google Photos? For instance, it's useful to include my folder of scanned photos but not my folder of desktop wallpapers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a text file with the name `.nomedia` into the folder you want to hide from the Photos app. The file itself can remain empty.

You can use a File Manager app to create files.

Comment: **This works**, even though it is not marked as the right answer. If you drag a folder with `.nomedia` into Google Photos directly, it will skip every file in this folder (and present you with a "skipped" icon in the upload).

Comment: Hey, is this still the case in 2019 as I have created a file called `.nomedia` and the photo's are still visible on my phone, I have also created a file called `.nomedia.txt` incase it did need to be a txt file and this is still the case.

Comment: I just tested this and it does not seem to work anymore. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

After poking around a bit, I found the following thing under the Google Photos settings: 
[image: Google Photos Setting Option]

It could easily be a new option, but seems to be exactly what you are after. You have to go to photos.google.com and then go to settings there, but it seems to work!

Comment: Isn't that the setting to use Drive images within Photos? The question is how to selectively sync those images (e.g., folder of camera photos but not a folder of receipt scans)